# How do i update a serviceUrl of the parent API set when creating an API operation using apiVersionSetId

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have this API Set created in BICEP code:

```
resource NamesApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-08-01' = {
  name: '${name}-api-transaction'
  parent: apimService
  properties: {
    displayName: 'Names APIs'
    apiRevision: '1'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    serviceUrl: nameSearchUrl
    path: 'internal/name'
    protocols: [
      'http'
      'https'
    ]
    authenticationSettings: {}
    subscriptionKeyParameterNames: {
      header: 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'
      query: 'subscription-key'
    }
    isCurrent: true    
  }
}
```

adding apiVersionSetId property to the above gives me a versioned API - all good.

Now how do I update the serviceUrl of the new api operation to the version that i have just created ?

Comment: You can use `set-backend-service` policy to update the service url

Comment: Have you tried with the `set-backend-service`? @William Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-backend-service-policy#examples) policy to update the `serviceUrl` of the new Api operation to the versioned API.

```bash
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2023-05")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://xxxx.com/api/8.2/" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2023-03")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://xxxx.com/api/9.1/" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

[image]